# Problem understanding this differential equation:

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The graph of $y = y(x)$ has this property: at each point (x, y) on the graph,
the normal line at that point passes through the fixed point (1, 0). (The normal is the line perpendicular
to the tangent line.)

why is that the $y(x)$ satisfies equation $y' = \frac{1-x}{y}$?

using separation of variables I get:

$$y = \mp \sqrt{2x-x^2+c}$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @StefanLafon why y(x) satisfies the differentail equation $y' = \frac{1-x}{y}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent to the curve at point $M=(x,y)$ has direction $(\frac{dx}{dx}=1, \frac{dy}{dx}=y^\prime)$. Thus the normal at that point has direction $(y^\prime, -1)$.

For point $A=(1,0)$ to be on that normal, you need vectors $\vec{AM}=(x-1, y-0)$ to be parallel to the normal's direction. Writing the determinant to be $0$ (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity#Collinearity_of_points_whose_coordinates_are_given) for an explanation) gives
$$(x-1)(-1)-y^\prime y=0$$
which means $$y^\prime = \frac{1-x}y$$

Comment: why vecotrs x-1 and y-0?

Comment: also can you add more detail in the determinant step

Comment: Take a look. I recommend you read up on determinants.

Comment: How do you find vector AM?

Comment: Given two points $A$ and $M$, do you know how to compute the coordinates of vector $\vec{AM}$?

Comment: I think so.....